# Spring struts2 asynchronous task

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I need to implement this functionality but I dont know to design and proceed on this.Please help me.

I have to import csv file from web ui. I used struts2(mvc)+spring(object injector)
I have done this task. But now the i have to import asynchronously i.e at a time many imports it should support. How can I do it?

I have done R&D. I found quartz. But can i use this?

Consider, I have two buttons. Clicking on first button it will go to first page there i can able to import cat1 type csv file containing 20k items. Clicking on second button it will go to another page there i can import cat2 type csv file containg 20k items.

How do i can implement it. Now its happening like at a time only one import can be done. but i want this to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your requirements, I don't think Quartz will be needed. Quartz is a scheduler and what you need is a Spring asynchronous task execution facilities.

Essentially, what is done, upon first call of async bean, control is immediately returned and the called async bean is handed off to Spring's `TaskExecutor` which further on controls the execution of the given method logic.

High-level overview of your options is as follows: you will need to inject a `TaskExecutor` bean implementation into Spring context and your asynchronous method logic will have to somehow perform the handoff either by

- (**XML-config**) wiring `TaskExecutor` as a collaborator inside your Spring bean containing method which you intend to execute asynchronously and calling execute() method of `TaskExecutor`, or
- (**annotation-config**) by marking the intended method with `@Async` annotation. Be advised, `TaskExecutor` implementation must be injected into Spring context.

Also, take note that should you want to return something from your asynchronous task, the return type must be an implementation of Java's `Future<T>` interface, which is a requirement since `TaskExecutor` is built on `java.concurrent.util.Executor` interface.

I can't comment on Struts, though, as I've never worked with it, but as far as I can tell, Struts should have no part in realizing asynchronicity - the heavy lifting is done by Spring alone.

For a more thorough and complete look on mentioned subject, I suggest starting with the following links:

- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#scheduling
- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Comment: No problem, that's what we're here for. And if the answer did indeed help you, please feel free to accept to answer and upvote it :o)